# AlertDialog Android

Tags: android, java

Доброго времени суток! возникла проблема при создании диалогов. Создаю диалог и при следующей необходимости открытия такого диалога открывается предыдущий(в том состоянии, в котором его закрыли). 
Вот вопрос в том, как удалять ненужные диалоги?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Их не нужно "удалять". Их нужно обновлять. Андроид считает, что  лучше один раз создать диалог и потом только поля обновлять, чем каждый раз создавать и удалять. Почитайте [короткую, но хорошую статью](http://startandroid.ru/ru/uroki/vse-uroki-spiskom/126-urok-65-dialogi-alertdialog-kastomizatsija.html).

Подсказка номер два. В onCreateDialog нужно создать диалог, но поля заполнять не нужно(кроме тех, которые общие для всех). Это как бы шаблон. А вот в onPrepareDialog нужно правильно заполнить диалог. Когда нужно отобразить диалог, то система проверит - если ли такой готовый. Если нет, она его создаст, вызвав onCreateDialog. А потом вызовет onPrepareDialog для отображения.

Answer (score 1):

[`removeDialog(id)`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#removeDialog(int))

А вообще, уже давно пора переходить на Fragment API — [`DialogFragment`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/DialogFragment.html). Он же [есть](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/app/DialogFragment.html) и в support library, для версий ниже 3.0.

Comment: а фраза "This method was deprecated in API level 13." не смущает?

Comment: Так я потому и написал про `DialogFragment`, если вы не заметили. Если уж на то пошло, то и `onCreateDialog` и `onPrepareDialog` объявлены как deprecated. Тем не менее, вы их советуете, и вас, судя по всему, такая же фраза вовсе не смущает. И вообще, ответ строился исходя из вопроса ТС.

Comment: DialogFragment я вижу. я просто помню, что removeDialog(id) сделали deprecated по другой причине - не вписывалось в архитектуру - удалять объекты так. Но потом понеслось. и задеприкейтили все.

Answer (score 1):

"Проблема" в том, что `Activity.onCreateDialog()` вызывается 1 раз, и в следующий раз при создании диалога используется уже ранее созданный образ.

Надо ловить `Activity.onPrepareDialog()`, который вызывается каждый раз при создании диалога и в нем переопределить состояние `Dialog`а

Если используете новомодный `DialogFragment`, то аналогом `onPrepareDialog()` будет `Fragment.onResume()`.